# Type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast error

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-freezed

In my sample project I implemented project with `riverpod` package and `freezed`. In the code below, I can get data from the server successfully, but when I try to use `model.fromJson` I get this error:

```
getting type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast
```

Server response data:

```json
{
  "message": "test message",
  "statusCode": 1
}
```

`login` model to cast data and structure of server response:

```dart
LoginModel loginModelFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> str) => LoginModel.fromJson(str);

String loginModelToJson(LoginModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

@freezed
class LoginModel with _$LoginModel {
  const factory LoginModel({
    required LoginResponse response,
  }) = _LoginModel;

  factory LoginModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$LoginModelFromJson(json);
}

@freezed
class LoginResponse with _$LoginResponse {
  const factory LoginResponse({
    required String message,
    required int statusCode,
  }) = _LoginResponse;

  factory LoginResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$LoginResponseFromJson(json);
}
```

Here on `LoginResponse` class I defined two parameters `message` and `statusCode` which are returned by server. When I try to use this request such as:

```dart
Future<LoginModel> getResponse(String mobileNumber) async {
  const endPoint = 'http://192.168.1.11/api';
  try {
    final response = await _read(dioProvider).get('${endPoint}/register');

    /*GETTING ERROR HERE*/
    return loginModelFromJson(response.data as Map<String, dynamic>);
  } on DioError catch (e) {
    ///
  }
}
```

I get the previously mentioned error on this line of `getResponse` method:

```
return loginModelFromJson(response.data as Map<String, dynamic>);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your response JSON is empty or contains incorrect content. That is why Dart is not able to cast it as `Map<String, dynamic>`. You have to do it manually

```dart
LoginResponse _$LoginResponseFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return LoginResponse(
    message: json['message'] as String,
    statusCode: json['statusCode'] as int,
  );
}
```

CHANGE

```dart
return loginModelFromJson(response.data as Map<String, dynamic>);
```

TO

```dart
return LoginResponse.fromJson(response.data);
```

Comment: i should edit `_$LoginResponseFromJson` in generated freezed class?

Comment: If you are using `json_serialize`, you should use `return LoginResponse.fromJson(response.data);`

Comment: i used `freezed` not `json_serialize`

Comment: It looks same usage for me as `json_serialize`

Comment: is this code correct? ```@freezed
class LoginResponse with _$LoginResponse {
  const factory LoginResponse({
    required String message,
    required int statusCode,
  }) = _LoginResponse;

  factory LoginResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$LoginResponseFromJson(json);
}``` could you help me how can i resolve that please?

Comment: I am not using `freezed`. If this code is autogenerated it is probably correct. Your usage of it is not. In Dart/Flutter you can't just cast directy to specific type. Dart is not that smart in most cases. See the edit of my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234890/discussion-between-doldurma-and-troncomputers).

Comment: for your updated code i get this error: `A value of type 'LoginResponse' can't be returned from the method 'getResponse' because it has a return type of 'Future<LoginModel>'. `

Answer (score 3):

you are getting a null response. Try this code and see if the error still there or not.

```
if(response.data!=null)
{return loginModelFromJson(response.data as Map<String, dynamic>);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `json.decode()` to obtain the Map<String, dynamic> object from json string.

Update the line `return loginModelFromJson(response.data as Map<String, dynamic>);` to `return loginModelFromJson(json.decode(response.data));`

Comment: i get this error: `type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

Comment: Could you put these 3 lines before the return statement and check the console output?
Need to see the exact value of the response.data
'print(response.data);
  Map<String, dynamic> parsed = json.decode(response.data);
  print(parsed);'

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution that helped me is null-safety!

This error can be handled by [**Dart null-safety**](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety).
Using all variables in the Model class with null-safety is a good practice.

Example for you can:

CHANGE below

```
required String message,
required int statusCode,
```

WITH

```
required String? message,
required int? statusCode,
```

And while using the variable you can use like:
`Text(message ?? ''),`